# Inner join with count on update query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
update posts 
set rank = (SELECT FIND_IN_SET( CONCAT(points, '_', comments_count, '_', created_at), 
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(points, '_', comments_count, '_', created_at) ORDER BY points desc, comments_count desc, created_at desc ) 
FROM (select *, COUNT(comments.id) as comments_count from posts) as posts_rankings INNER JOIN comments ON comments.post_id = posts_rankings.id)))
```

I want get count of comments on every post and next orderBy with this count. How I can do this? Now me get error:: `unknown column comments.id in field list`

My tables structure:

[image]

[image]

I calculate rank of post depending on order the `points`, `comments_count` and `created_at`.

Comment: Do you have column `id` in `posts` table?

Comment: This subquery makes no sense `select *, COUNT(comments.id) as comments_count from posts` You can't count from a different table than the one you're selecting from.

Comment: The subquery also needs to be correlated with the main query, so you get the rank of that row.

Comment: @Barmar can you post answer with example ? Thanks.

Comment: I started to write an answer, but I couldn't finish it because I don't really understand what you're counting and ranking. I don't know your table definitions so I can't tell how everything should be joined.

Comment: You also need to change the subquery to a join, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause

Comment: The subqueries with `COUNT()` and `GROUP_CONCAT()` both need to use `GROUP BY`, but I don't know what you're grouping.

Comment: @Barmar I updated a question. Please see and post answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't select the grouped and non-grouped values in the same subquery. You need two subqueries, one to do the `GROUP_CONCAT()` of all the posts, and another to get the value for each specific post and get its rank in the concatenated list.

```
UPDATE posts AS p
JOIN (
    SELECT p1.id, FIND_IN_SET(CONCAT_WS('_', p1.points, p1.comments_count, p1.created_at), all_post_counts) AS rank
    FROM (
        SELECT p.id, p.created_at, p.points, IFNULL(COUNT(c.id), 0) AS comments_count
        FROM posts AS p
        LEFT JOIN comments AS c ON c.post_id = p.id
        GROUP BY p.id
    ) AS p1
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('_', p1.points, p1.comments_count, p1.created_at) ORDER BY points desc, comments_count desc, created_at desc) AS all_post_counts
        FROM (
            SELECT p.id, p.created_at, p.points, IFNULL(COUNT(c.id), 0) AS comments_count
            FROM posts AS p
            LEFT JOIN comments AS c ON c.post_id = p.id
            GROUP BY p.id
        ) AS p1
    ) AS p3
) AS p4
ON p.id = p4.id
SET p.rank = p4.rank
```

Make sure you set `group_concat_max_len` large enough to hold all the results in that subquery.

Comment: `IFNULL(COUNT(c.id),0)...LEFT JOIN...` Eh?

Comment: @Strawberry That's needed to get zero counts for posts with no comments.

Comment: @Barmar but if I have a type column in comments table and I want calculate rank posts only with comments  where type = 1 ?

Comment: Um, one of us is suffering from acute coffee deficiency. It might be me - but I am on my 3rd cup !?!

Comment: @Dronaxer Add that to the `ON` clause: `LEFT JOIN comments AS c on c.post_id = p.id AND c.type = 1`

Comment: @Barmar perfect! Thanks.